# How to setup automatic shutdown for Google Compute Instance?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm running a NodeJS app inside a docker container inside a container-optimized-OS GCE instance.

I need this instance to shutdown an self-delete upon its task completion. Only the NodeJS app is aware of the task completion.

I used to achieve this behavior by setting up this as a `startup-script`:

```sh
node ./dist/app.js

echo "node script execution finished. Deleting this instance"
export NAME=$(curl -X GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/name -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google')
export ZONE=$(curl -X GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google')
gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances my-group --instances=$NAME --zone=$ZONE
```

I've also used similar setups with additional logic based on the NodeJS app exit code.

How do I do it now?

There are two problems:

1. I don't know how to pass NodeJS exit event (preferably with exit code) up to the `startup-script`. How do I do that?
2. Container-optimized-OS GCE instance lacks `gcloud`. Is there different way of shutting down an instance?

Google Cloud's Healthcheck seems too troublesome and not universal. My app is not a web-server, I prefer not to install `express` or something else just for sake of handling health checks.

Right now my `startup-script` ends with `docker run ...` command. Maybe I should write the shutdown command after that and somehow make docker exit on NodeJS exit?

If you think the Healthcheck is the way to go, what would be the lightest setup for a health check given that my app is not a web-server?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to have your app trigger a Cloud Function when the app finishes the job
2. Cloud function can then have script to delete your VM. See sample script below

https://medium.com/google-cloud/start-stop-compute-engine-instance-from-cloud-function-bf9ae5199609